# Error al guardar un archivo txt en R a través del docker

Tags: r, docker, txt

Estoy intentando guardar un archivo .txt de una sesión de R que se ejecuta a través del docker.
Para ejecutar esta imagen de docker corre el siguiente código:

```
     docker run -e PASSWORD=xxx --rm -p xxx:xxx -v ~/ad_R:/home/rstudio/ad_R -v ~/ad_data:/home/rstudio/ad_data rocker/tidyverse
```

No muestro por aquí la contraseña ni el puerto en el que se ejecutan.

No obstante mi pregunta es, cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
     write.table(all_blast_vir_updated,file="/home/rstudio/ad_R/all_blast_vir_updated.txt",sep="\t")
```

Me da este error:

```
     Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
     cannot open the connection
     In addition: Warning message:
     In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
     cannot open file '/home/rstudio/ad_R/all_blast_vir_updated.txt': Permission denied
```

cuando corro el siguiente código en la terminal de R:

```
system('ls -ld ad_R;ls -ld ad_data')
```

obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  9 10:06 ad_R
   drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 516 Jul  6 15:06 ad_data


    docker inspect rocker/tidyverse

    [
{
    "Id": "sha256:93f0dfaee7413331b085e3353ecfd99de4c95a3c38344f367a1e20938f350a94",
    "RepoTags": [
        "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    ],
    "RepoDigests": [
        "rocker/tidyverse@sha256:0fcc86754ed90b3e5a3dcaed27ad967de2859705f85c28d9284e16aa9856548b"
    ],
    "Parent": "",
    "Comment": "",
    "Created": "2018-10-16T05:21:13.292396576Z",
    "Container": "a3083823beca98108c9b0239bd26453dba04d2ffd7aabb002e3c4d4ce26e0865",
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "Hostname": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8787/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "R_VERSION=3.5.1",
            "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "TERM=xterm",
            "S6_VERSION=v1.21.4.0",
            "S6_BEHAVIOUR_IF_STAGE2_FAILS=2"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install   libxml2-dev   libcairo2-dev   libsqlite3-dev   libmariadbd-dev   libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev   libpq-dev   libssh2-1-dev   unixodbc-dev   && install2.r --error     --deps TRUE     tidyverse     dplyr     devtools     formatR     remotes     selectr     caTools     BiocManager"
        ],
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:21494863674fd4db806d16b96ff96e35a960dae5883ecf73a9bb343584beb822",
        "Volumes": {
            "/home/rstudio/kitematic": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": "Carl Boettiger <cboettig@ropensci.org>",
            "org.label-schema.license": "GPL-2.0",
            "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned",
            "org.label-schema.vendor": "Rocker Project"
        }
    },
    "DockerVersion": "18.03.1-ee-3",
    "Author": "",
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8787/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "R_VERSION=3.5.1",
            "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "TERM=xterm",
            "S6_VERSION=v1.21.4.0",
            "S6_BEHAVIOUR_IF_STAGE2_FAILS=2"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/init"
        ],
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:21494863674fd4db806d16b96ff96e35a960dae5883ecf73a9bb343584beb822",
        "Volumes": {
            "/home/rstudio/kitematic": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": "Carl Boettiger <cboettig@ropensci.org>",
            "org.label-schema.license": "GPL-2.0",
            "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned",
            "org.label-schema.vendor": "Rocker Project"
        }
    },
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Size": 1809809643,
    "VirtualSize": 1809809643,
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": null,
        "Name": "aufs"
    },
    "RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:f715ed19c28b66943ac8bc12dbfb828e8394de2530bbaf1ecce906e748e4fdff",
            "sha256:3f4e4e58bfe2eb291704c6d4f0290cbef16f186782c91874603b329f8b4fcdeb",
            "sha256:3464d59c63ca738b514b2326b9ab5ae1f98ce1d745b0550c8ef8575dea82e468",
            "sha256:361124d095ab256af24832a87dc2a8284093131f0883b139cce71880a2b4cbbb",
            "sha256:d765234a779c9d92af39bdc0520bfffb0ccbcd7818fc22078b1fd6c6fedc4fd0",
            "sha256:d04dffe8baa928e83dd2f27bf565178b9e05bcb32887c8cfdb13141d6bd16fee",
            "sha256:f7f8979b332ebb6b415039d555c4a3d0e29977eb8b4686dafd057763e1efac41",
            "sha256:32d792b4b56e294f7e75dd76f7d6f546881996231016a26835594aa6a9112824"
        ]
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

]

¿Cuál es mi problema?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110739/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-p-l-error-al-guardar-un-archivo-txt-en-r-a-tra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de permisos en las carpetas que mencionas, tienen un dueño, que no es el mismo con el que estás ejecutando la instancia de **Rstudio** con **docker**, de ahí el error de permisos al salvar. Esto lo puedes verificar mediante :

```
# ls -ld ad_R
```

Primero una explicación de permisos, ownership y otros temas: Understanding [Basic File Permissions and ownership in Linux](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-basic-file-permissions-and-ownership-in-linux/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según comentaste, una de tu carpetas arroja esta información:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  9 10:06 ad_R
```

El permiso es bastante común, le da privilegios de lectura, escritura y ejecución, al dueño de la carpeta y le quita la posibilidad de escritura al resto de los usuarios que forman parte del mismo grupo del dueño o a los otros (los que no son el dueño o parte del grupo del dueño).

Cualquier usuario que no sea el dueño, podrá ver el contenido de la carpeta **pero no podrá salvar nada en ella.** En este caso, el dueño, es el super usuario `root`, algo "extraño" ya que en el `home` de un usuario no `root` uno esperaría ver que el dueño de las carpetas es el propio usuario, esto me hace pensar que la creación de estas carpetas las hizo directamente el `root`

Finalmente **vale decir que si no eres `root` no tendrás posibilidad de salvar nada en estas carpetas**, no es un problema de docker, es un problema de permisos a nivel del SO, lo cual puedes verificar simplemente intentando crear cualquier contenido:

```
touch ~/ad_R/prueba.txt
```

`~` es el alias del `home` del usuario activo. Deberías obtener un error similar a esto:

```
touch: no se puede efectuar `touch' sobre '/home/tu_home/prueba.txt': Permiso denegado
```

#### ¿Y cómo lo solucionamos?

Depende de lo que el sistema te permita hacer, acá van una serie de opciones:

#### Trabajar con un usuario común No `root`

Esto es lo mejor y habitual en entornos `linux`, cuando ingresas al servidor, lo haces mediante un usuario, que siempre podrás consultar mediante `whoami`. Salvo que la instalación sea una catástrofe, deberías poder crear carpetas nuevas y estas heredar tu "ownership", por lo que debería funcionar algo así:

```
mkdir ~/ad_R_nuevo
mkdir ~/ad_data_nuevo

docker run -e PASSWORD=xxx --rm -p xxx:xxx -v ~/ad_R_nuevo:/home/rstudio/ad_R -v ~/ad_data_nuevo:/home/rstudio/ad_data rocker/tidyverse
```

En este caso "mapeamos" las carpetas nuevas a los nombres de volúmenes que ya manejabas, no tiene que ser necesariamente el mismo nombre de la carpeta física. **Esto debería permitirte salvar en `ad_R` y `ad_data`.**

#### Trabajar directamente como `root`

No es lo mejor, pero si es posible iniciar una sesión directamente como `root`, es raro, por que tu usuario y carpeta `home` es otro, pero si quieres seguir usando las carpetas ya creadas esta es una forma.

(a). Puedes iniciar la sesión directamente como `root` y luego ir a la carpeta de trabajo, por ejemplo: `cd /home/lab227`

(b). Puedes iniciar tu sesión normalmente y luego impersonarte como `root` mediante el comando `su`, ingresas la contraseña y listo. Verifica que seas efectivamente el superusuario mediante `whoami`

De cualquiera de las formas, ahora eres el dueño de las carpetas, deberías iniciar la instancia de docker como lo haces y no tener más problemas (al menos este).

(c) Puedes correr un comando desde un usuario común, pero, como `root`, por ejemplo, usando `sudo`:

```
sudo docker run -e PASSWORD=xxx --rm -p xxx:xxx -v ~/ad_R_nuevo:/home/rstudio/ad_R -v ~/ad_data_nuevo:/home/rstudio/ad_data rocker/tidyverse
```

#### ¿Y no podemos cambiar el ownership de las carpetas?

Si, también es posible pero claramente lo tiene que hacer el super usuario o el dueño (en este caso el mismo), el dueño lo cambias así, en este caso **logeado como el usuario común**:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/ad_R
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/ad_data
```

En este caso `$USER` es el alias del usuario activo. Luego puede verificar los permisos, por ejemplo si tu usuario es `lab227`:

```
 ls -ld ~/ad_R
 ls -ld ~/ad_data
```

Debieras tener una salida como esta:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 3 lab227 lab227 4096 Jul  9 10:06 ad_R

 drwxr-xr-x 3 lab227 lab227 4096 Jul  9 10:06 ad_data
```

Así como se ve, es lo mínimo necesario que vas a necesitar para que la instancia de **Rstudio** iniciada como `lab227`  en **docker** pueda funcionar. De hecho, tal vez esto sea lo más simple y lo que deberías probar primero.

Comment: BINGO! Patricio , la segunda y tercera opción me funcionó perfectamente. Muchas gracias por la paciencia y por todas las opciones que has hecho. De nuevo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos son de propietario root y grupo root, ¿tu programa también se ejecuta como root? Yo me decanto mas por comprobar los permisos de acceso.

También puedes ejecutar `docker inspect <volume_name>` para ver si el volumen es RW o RO y esta montado correctamente.

Comment: Hola Carlos, he introducido ese código y el output está en la edición de esta pregunta. Por favor, revisalo

Comment: Si haces un "docker exec -ti <container_id> ls -la /home/rstudio" te aparecen los directorios?

Comment: He probado con el ide y con el nombre del contenedor : docker exec -ti rocker/tidyverse ls -la /home/rstudio y docker exec -ti 93f0dfaee741 ls -la /home/rstudio y en ambos casos obtengo el mismo resultado: Error: No such container: rocker/tidyverse y Error: No such container: 93f0dfaee741

Comment: Mete en tu programa algo que lo deje pillado, como un sleep() y repite a ver